# Techniques for convex optimization over a vertex-representation of a polytope?

Tags: convex-optimization, combinatorial-geometry, polytopes, convex-hulls

I have a convex optimization problem where the feasible region is defined as the convex hull of a set of vertices.  Even though the vertex set is in the low dozens of points, finding the half-space (H-) representation of the polytope looks intractable.  So I don't have a standard-format set of constraints to plug into the usual techniques.

Are there any transformations that would let me work around this and directly optimize over the V-representation?

I would be willing to do something like hill-climbing, but since I still have to test polytope-membership, I'm not sure if I gain anything.

Just in case it helps, the polytope is fairly degenerate (e.g. ~50-dimensional but in an ambient space of about 80 dimensions).  It has a high degree of symmetry (although I don't know the symmetry group, I may have enough information to get it).  My sketchy understanding is that the symmetry and degeneracy both make it harder to use standard techniques.  It's also a 0/1-polytope (every vertex has either 0 or 1 for every coordinate.)

I could possibly use these facts to reduce the cost of getting the H-representation, but I don't know of any techniques for that and would be headed into unknown territory; I'd also appreciate literature pointers in that direction.

Comment: Why do you need the H-representation? A point $x$ in the polytope satisfies $x=\sum_it_i v_i$ with $t_i\geq 0$, $\sum t_i=1$. These are just additional linear constraints in $x$ and the auxiliary variables $t_i$.

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek, That looks to me like an answer to the question.  I suggest writing that as an answer, so we can upvote it, and so the question is treated as answered.

Comment: Yes, @MichalAdamaszek, please answer so I can accept this.  Thanks!